# How to include nested model in HTTP response?

Tags: javascript, node.js, loopbackjs, loopback

just wondering how to include a belongsTo related object in the response when creating the parent object using a POST reqeust. I have tried loading the related object in the 'after save' hook, but it does not get returned in the response, only the foreign key.

Eg.

/teams/1/members POST

```
{ name: 'person1' }
```

Expected response:

```
{name:'person1', team:{id:1}}
```

Actual response:

```
{name:'person1', teamId: 1}
```

Is it possible? If not, is there a work around?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a [remote after create hook](https://docs.strongloop.com/display/public/LB/Remote+hooks).

```
  Team.afterRemote('*.__create__members', async (ctx, member, next) => {
    try {
      member.__data.team = await Team.findById(member.teamId)
      next()
    } catch (err) {
      next(err)
    }
  })
```

Comment: Very nice! It's the __data that made it work for me. It feels like a workaround though so I'll hold off a bit before accepting your answer. Thanks!

Comment: Sure! If someone comes up with a better answer, it's better for everyone. I found a [related issue](https://github.com/strongloop/loopback/issues/1094) on GitHub. Maybe it can give you some more insight. These kind of issues are usually tackled by [include filter](https://docs.strongloop.com/display/public/LB/Include+filter) + [default scope](https://docs.strongloop.com/display/public/LB/Model+definition+JSON+file#ModeldefinitionJSONfile-Defaultscope), but there is no filtering for a *create* method. Maybe another possibility is to redefine it.